# How to get random number field for each invoice apart its invoice number?

Tags: invoice

What to do to get random number with each invoice apart from invoice number that can be viewed in `Admin side Invoices table, customer account view order or invoice pdf`?

Whenever any invoice is created, it will have one random number like "3456445354" or "4467575756". It is used to third party verification whether the order is legit or not.

Can anybody help to get this thing?

Comment: hi frinds please visit http://open-tools.net/documentation/advanced-order-numbers-for-magento.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new attribute to the sales_flat_order_invoice table whith a default value set to a random number. Try something like this, create an upgrade script:

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$connection = $this->getConnection();

$this->addAttribute('sales_flat_order_item', 'random_number', array(
    'label' => 'Random Number',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'position' => 1,
    'visible_on_front'  => true,
    'default' => 'FLOOR(((CURTIME()+0)*1000000)*RAND())',
));

$this->endSetup();
```

Then each time a new invoice is generated the new attribute will get a random number generated automatically by Mysql

Comment: Where do I add this code?
So if I see the invoice which was already generated, then it will show the same number which was generated at the first time when that invoice is generated?

Comment: Check this post, jump to the Install Update Script part. It explains how the update scripts work: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

Comment: Ok. I will check it out and let u know. Thank u so much.